# What if a browser does not understand the secure flag of a cookie?

Tags: tls, web-browser, http, cookies

I have two related questions:

1. As `HttpOnly` attribute is understood by [a set of modern browsers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Browsers_Supporting_HttpOnly), I was wondering if there is a list of all browsers which support the `secure` flag of the cookie?
2. What would happend if a browser does not support the `secure` flag but an application sets it on the cookie?

Comment: did you find a mainstream browser which does not support secure flag?

Comment: @SachinKumar: Good to see you here :) 
I am not sure about the browser versions which don't support secure flag. Actually I was just wondering if there are people using old browser versions, setting secure attribute will work for them or not and to test this I would at least need such specific versions which don't support cookie's secure flag :(

Comment: people on such old browsers versions have a lot of others things to worry about. You setting secure flag on their session cookies will not really help them a lot, they are the daredevils and don't care about being compromised ;)

Comment: yep yep :) I have a meeting with such daredevils ;) will use your last comment as my initial speech :P

Comment: ;Secure is supported by all common browsers since 1997 (!); probably earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not seen a formal list of browsers which support secure but definitely in my experience all the recent iterations of popular browsers do.

My guess for what would happen if you found a browser that didn't support the flag, in the event that it was passed, is that it would just ignore the flag, although I suppose it would also be possible that it would ignore the whole cookie.

If you wanted to test it, one option might be to try setting a junk flag on a cookie (say with a random name) and see how browsers react to it.

Overall I'd say it's unlikely to be a problem unless your application is supporting very old or obscure browsers.

Comment: Indeed, any browser that is compliant with the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265) will support the `secure` attribute (and, for that matter, the `httpOnly` attribute too). Only old versions would be relevant for this, and those are not secure anyway...

Answer (score 3):

What do you call a browser that doesn't support the `secure` flag?  Broken!

Fortunately, every browser you're ever likely to use should support it.  The `secure` flag has been part of the spec from since the earliest days of the Internet, and should be essentially universally supported.  If you find a browser that doesn't support it, you get a cookie :-), that's a bug.

In short: Don't bother spending your time worrying about the possibility of a browser that doesn't support the `secure` flag.  There are better things to worry about.